# dynamically populating comboboxes in php using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, combobox

I have written a code in which I am trying to populate dropdown by selecting the option from a different dropdown. I've googled and figured out that this is possible with javascript. But I am getting an error while passing php array to javascript in `onchange()` method of first combo box. Array is perfectly fine, it's giving me the desired results but error occurs when I try to populate it... it show uninitialized variable error... but I am unable to find a way to set value for it.

```html
 <?php
    session_start(); // NEVER forget this!
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
    {
        die("To access this page, you need to <a href='main_login.php'>LOGIN</a>"); 
    } 
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
    var name=document.forms["form1"]["name"].value;
    var passno=document.forms["form1"]["passno"].value;
    var applicationno=document.forms["form1"]["applicationno"].value;
    var price=document.forms["form1"]["price"].value;
    var date=document.forms["form1"]["date"].value;
    var reg = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d/;
    if ((name=="" || name==null) || (passno=="" || passno==null) || (applicationno=="" || applicationno==null || isNaN(applicationno) ) || (price=="" || price==null || isNaN(price)) || (date=="" || date==null || date=="00-00-0000" || !date.match(reg)))
      {
      alert("Applicant Name, Passport Number, Application Number,Price And Date Must Be Filled Out.\n\n Valid Date Format Is : (dd-mm-yyyy) \n\n Only numbers are allowed for Application Number and Price.");
      return false;
      }
      else {
          return true;

            }
    }
    function fillDate(array1,array2)
    {
        document.form1.subagentname.options.add( new Option(array1,array2) );
        }
  </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    input.uppercase { 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1 align="center">ADD VISA DETAILS</h1>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="insertvisa.php" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
    <p>
        <label for="name">APPLICANT NAME : * </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"/>
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="company">COMPANY : </label>
        <select name="company" id="company">
          <option value="TULIP TOURISM LLC">TULIP TOURISM LLC</option>
          <option value="TULIP TRAVELS LLC">TULIP TRAVELS LLC</option>
          <option value="EXCELLENT MARINA">EXCELLENT MARINA</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="nationality">NATIONALITY : </label>
        <input type="text" name="nationality" id="nationality" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="passno">PASSPORT NUMBER : * </label>
        <input type="text" name="passno" id="passno" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="applicationno">APPLICATION NUMBER : * </label>
        <input type="text" name="applicationno" id="applicationno" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="proctype">PROCEDURE TYPE : </label>
        <select name="proctype" id="proctype">
          <option value="NORMAL">NORMAL</option>
          <option value="URGENT">URGENT</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="visatype">VISA TYPE : </label>
        <select name="visatype" id="visatype">
          <option value="TOURIST">TOURIST</option>
          <option value="SERVICE">SERVICE</option>
          <option value="TT">TT</option>
          <option value="EXTENSION">EXTENSION</option>
          <option value="CANCELLATION">CANCELLATION</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="agent">AGENT : </label>
        <?php 

    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="hp";
    $link=mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Cannot connect to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

    $dbname = 'apcom_visa_system';
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Cannot connect to database: ".mysql_error());

    $query="SELECT agent_id,agent_name FROM agent";

    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ('error submitting');

    echo "<select name='agentname' id='agentname' onChange='return fillData(htmlspecialchars(json_encode($subagentsID), ENT_NOQUOTES),htmlspecialchars(json_encode($subagentsName), ENT_NOQUOTES));'>";
    while($drop=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    //data stored in $drop
    echo "<option value='$drop[agent_id]'>$drop[agent_name]</option>";
    $agentsID[]=$drop[agent_id];

    }
    echo "</select>"; 

    foreach($agentsID as $values)
    {
        //echo "agents-->".$values;

    $query1="SELECT subagent_id,subagent_name FROM subagent WHERE agent_id=$values";

    $result1 = mysql_query ($query1) or die ('error submitting');

    while($drop1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $subagentsID[]=$drop1['subagent_id'];
    $subagentsName[]=$drop1['subagent_name'];

        //echo "subagents-->".$drop1['subagent_id'];
    }


        }


    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="subagentname">SUBAGENT : </label>
      <select name="subagentname" id="subagentname"></select>
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="cost">COST : </label>
        <select name="cost" id="cost">
          <option value="210">210</option>
          <option value="310">310</option>
          <option value="610">610</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="price">PRICE : * </label>
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"/>
        <label for="currency"></label>
        <select name="currency" id="currency">
          <option value="AED">AED</option>
          <option value="PKR">PKR</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="status">STATUS : </label>
        <select name="status" id="status">
          <option value="APPLICATION NOT POSTED">APPLICATION NOT POSTED</option>
          <option value="APPLICATION POSTED">APPLICATION POSTED</option>
          <option value="APPLICATION INPROCESS">APPLICATION INPROCESS</option>
          <option value="APPLICATION REJECTED">APPLICATION REJECTED</option>
          <option value="APPLICATION APPROVED">APPLICATION APPROVED</option>
          <option value="DOCUMENTS REQUIRED">DOCUMENTS REQUIRED</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="date">APPLICATION DATE : * </label>
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
    (DATE FORMAT : dd-MM-yyyy , Example : 11-05-2012) </p>
      <p>
      <p>
      * Required
      </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="document.location.href='main.php';return false;"/>
      </p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).  Also, you seem to be connecting every time you run a query.  You don't need to do that.

Comment: thnx charles.. i was connecting again n agin.. now edited. but kindly any solution to my real problem.

Comment: @m_kiani Right, it isn't a solution, but its a hint to another problem you have: You use the `mysql`-extension. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: what's the exact error text?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: subagentsID in C:\wamp\www\tulip\addvisa.php on line 102

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the second dropdown using php, change it using javascript. On changing the first dropdown, make an ajax call to a page( which is same as what you are doing now for getting the data for the second dropdown, instead of having it on the same page create a new page which returns the list of options for the second dropdown)  which gives you the list of options that has to be shown in the second dropdown.